# How to develop multiple Trigger.io plugins in a team?

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins, workflow, trigger.io

Together with my team I'm developing multiple native plugins based on Trigger.io. Since the recent changes I'm not completely sure on the workflow and cannot find anything about it in the documentation either. Some questions that arise:

1) Should one set of inspector projects be used for all the plugins or should each plugin has its own set?

2) Which parts of the inspector projects should be maintained via version control, which should remain local? *(fyi: we use SVN)*

3) (Android) When using one inspector project for each plugin, whats the best way to import them all as Java projects in Eclipse? Note: each inspector project has 3 sub projects which have the same name across different plugins, so they'd have to renamed? Assuming I have 5 plugins in development, that'd mean that I have to import 15 Java projects into Eclipse. Is this really how it's meant to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most effective way to develop plugins is still something we're working on, how things are right now is probably not as good as it could be (especially for developing multiple plugins), but as things are right now:

1) Each plugin should have its own set of inspector projects.

2) The majority of what the Toolkit puts in the plugins folder is probably best in version control. Things you can safely ignore are the `.trigger` folder and any `bin`, `gen`, or `build` folders in the inspector projects. If you are trying to keep less files in version control the things you definitely need are the `assets/src` folder in the `ForgeInspector`, and any of your own source in `ForgeModule`, the rest of the inspector project should be regenerated by the Toolkit.

3) I'd recommend using an eclipse workspace per plugin, as the Toolkit regenerates a lot of the code when you update the inspector I don't think it is currently possible to rename the projects.

---

I thought I'd include a quick overview of what the 3 projects are and why there are 3:

`ForgeCore` - This is the pre-build core library for Trigger.io apps, its used by both `ForgeInspector` and `ForgeModule` so it needs to be a separate project that can be referenced by both

`ForgeInspector` - This is meant to replicate as closely as possible how your plugin will actually be used, so is basically a stripped down Trigger.io app, its separate to `ForgeModule` so that you can see what code is in your plugin and what code needs to be put into build_steps.json so it will also be applied to a real Trigger.io app at build time.

`ForgeModule` - This contains your plugin code

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! 1) and 2) are pretty much what I already expected. There is definitely room for improvement on the third point. It might even be possible to rename the projects as Eclipse should automatically update the references.

Comment: For 3) I've made it so in the future (I'm not certain when this change will be deployed just now) the eclipse projects will be prefixed with the plugin name (i.e. `alert_ForgeModule`, `alert_ForgeCore`, `alert_ForgeInspector`) which lets you import multiple plugins into the same workspace without any extra changes.

Comment: This is live in platform v1.4.27, you'll need to change the platform version in the plugins manifest.json to see the changes (and probably remove and re-import the eclipse projects). I'm also finding working sets in eclipse useful for organising so many projects, there is a guide on how to set them up here: http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2005/06/19/organizing-eclipse-projects-with-working-sets/

Comment: Another quick update, there was a bug in v1.4.27, v1.4.29 should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try out the improvements soon.